# Security Exception in Accessing Amazon SQS from IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis, amazon-sqs

I have configured the Amazon SQS for Email and push message on my local system and it is working fine while hosting from the iis in the lan as well but i am getting the problem shared hosting and i am getting the below exception stack trace.

Security Exception

Description: The application attempted to perform an operation not allowed by the security policy.  To grant this application the required permission please contact your system administrator or change the application's trust level in the configuration file.

Exception Details: System.Security.SecurityException: Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

[SecurityException: Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.]    AmazonHelper.QueueHelperIntilization() +234    ws32_message..ctor() +100    ASP.admin_message_aspx..ctor() +14
__ASP.FastObjectFactory_app_web_oochbvqy.Create_ASP_admin_message_aspx()
+20    System.Web.Compilation.BuildResultCompiledType.CreateInstance() +32    System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath(VirtualPath virtualPath, Type requiredBaseType, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp) +109    System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory.GetHandlerHelper(HttpContext context, String requestType, VirtualPath virtualPath, String physicalPath) +31  System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory.System.Web.IHttpHandlerFactory2.GetHandler(HttpContext context, String requestType, VirtualPath virtualPath, String physicalPath) +40    System.Web.HttpApplication.MapHttpHandler(HttpContext context, String requestType, VirtualPath path, String pathTranslated, Boolean useAppConfig) +167    System.Web.MapHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
+128    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +184

Please let me know if somebody have answer.

Thanks a million.

Comment: Could it be when you pushed the dll's they got blocked? Right click into the dll properties and make sure they aren't blocked.

Comment: The dll is unlocked already...